# Software issue with audio being cross-mixed between channels

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, sound-card

This is my Windows 10 laptop from work, a Dell XPS 13, with Realtek Audio driver version 6.0.1.8475.

When listening to audio through the headphones jack on the laptop itself, the audio gets downmixed into a "half-mono" mix where left channel plays on both channels (but louder on the left), and right channel plays on both channels too (but louder on the right).

I have isolated the problem to be 100% a software issue: if I adjust the balance (at Device properties→Levels) to shut off one of the channels, the (already-downmixed) sound is properly cut completely from that channel. So all hardware is working as expected (no shorting, no half-plugged jack, no TRRS↔TRS incompatibility, no lint in the socket, …)

I have disabled Spatial sound, and don't have any Realtek programs/applets/system tray tools running.

Anything else I should be looking into?

Comment: I posted [this question in a different wording earlier](https://superuser.com/questions/1489165/stereo-mixed-down-to-almost-mono-both-right-and-left-speakers-output-right-an), but it got inexplicably downvoted and I only got comments relating to hardware issues.

Comment: Additional clarifications: * happens with audio coming from any application. * Happens with any pair of good quality headphones that work fine when plugged to other equipment. * Does not happen with USB headphones plugged to the computer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stereo mixed down to "almost mono" (both right and left speakers output right and left channels, in different mixing)](https://superuser.com/questions/1489165/stereo-mixed-down-to-almost-mono-both-right-and-left-speakers-output-right-an)